# How to solve db connection failer in ssis 2008 version?

Tags: ssis

In ssis 2005  i have created a package configuration and closed the package. When i  re-open the package I'm getting  db connection failed error. For this i gave Db credential in connection manager and the error automatically cleared. This is not happening in when i tried in ssis 2008 package .

how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the password of your connection string, you have to set the package option  `ProtectionLevel` to any value other than `DontSaveSensitive`. This way, it will be remembered when you reopen the package.

Comment: In my package default ProtectionLevel is "EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey" but also I'm getting  db connection failed error occurred in 2008 ssis .